# JQUERY Mobile: Dynamic append list not working

Tags: jquery, list, mobile, dynamic, popup

Im new to Jquery Mobile and I have some issues with the following.

What I try to build is:
- Have a button. When I click on the button a popup will be showned
- In the popup you can enter some input and submit by pressing the button.
- After that, what has been entered should be added to the list.

What happens is the following:
- When you press the button, the popup is shown
- You can enter a value in the input and submit. This works as expected.
- After that I see that the value is added twice to the list and then the page refresh and the items disappear from the list.
- After I used the button to show the popupbox, the button is not working again.

So I have the following questions:
- Why is the input added twice to the list?
- Why is my page refreshing and removes the list item that just is added?
- Why is my button not working when I used it 1 time?

I have read many hours on the internet and tried a lot, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Hereby the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Test App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Home screen icon  Mathias Bynens http://goo.gl/6nVq0 --> 
    <!-- For iPhone 4 with high-resolution Retina display: --> 
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
     <!-- For first-generation iPad: --> 
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
     <!-- For non-Retina iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android 2.1+ devices: --> 
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
     <!-- For nokia devices: --> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="home" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">  
            <h1>Test App</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
            <ul id="personenLijst" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="b">
                <li data-role="list-divider">Personenlijst</li>
            </ul>
            <div align="center">
            <a href="#popupLogin" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop" data-position-to="window" data-rel="popup" data-mini="true" data-theme="b">Persoon Toevoegen</a>
            </div>
            <div id="popupMenu" data-role="popup" data-theme="a">    
                <div id="popupLogin" class="ui-corner-all" data-role="popup" data-theme="a">        
                    <form>            
                    <div style="padding: 10px 20px;">              
                    <h3>Voer persoonsnaam in</h3>              
                    <label class="ui-hidden-accessible" for="persoon">Persoon:</label>              
                    <input id="persoon" name="persoon" value="" type="text" data-theme="a" placeholder="persoon">              
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check">Persoon Toevoegen</button>            

                    </div>        
                    </form>    

                    <script>
                    $("#submit").on("click", function () {
                        list = '<li>' + $("#persoon").val() + '</li>';
                        $("#personenLijst").append(list);
                        window.setTimeout(function(){ $("#personenLijst").listview("refresh"); },300);

                        //$("#personenLijst").selectmenu('refresh');
                    });

                    </script>

                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="info"></a>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks for your help!

regards,
Victor

Answer (score 0):

You are using submit button hence form getting submitted and page reloading. This is causing your page to refresh.

Change button type to `type="button"`

```
<button type="button" id="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check">
  Persoon Toevoegen
</button>
```

Keep your script inside `document.ready`, this will ensure that all DOM structure is ready before assigning any event handler

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").on("click", function () {
       list = '<li>' + $("#persoon").val() + '</li>';
       $("#personenLijst").append(list);
         window.setTimeout(function(){ $("#personenLijst").listview("refresh");
       },300);
       //$("#personenLijst").selectmenu('refresh');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, that indeed helps a part of the issue :) The site is not refreshing anymore, thanks!<BR><BR>It does add the items twice to the list. Do you know why?

Comment: what happens when you remove `$("#personenLijst").listview("refresh");`, have you tried that?